# capture RTSP stream from IP camera ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp

I used the following command to get the frames from RTSP h264 codec. I could not able to get the frames from the ip camera.

```
$ ffmpeg -i rtsp://xxxx:yyy@192.168.1.yy:xx/tcp/av0_0 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/120 img%03d.jpg
```

My output

```
ffmpeg version 3.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 

  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab --disable-yasm

  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100

  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101

  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100

  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101

  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100

  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100

  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100

  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100

[rtsp @ 0x2dba3a0] CSeq 6 expected, 0 received.
    Last message repeated 5 times

[rtsp @ 0x2dba3a0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size

Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options

Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, rtsp, from 
'rtsp://xx:yy@192.168.1.xx:yy/tcp/av0_0':

  Metadata:

    title           : streamed by the RTSP server

  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s

    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc

    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 64 kb/s

Output #0, image2, to 'img%03d.jpg':

Output file #0 does not contain any stream

Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Comment: As per the ffmpeg tag text: `Questions here should involve programmatic use of the libraries, API, or tools. Questions about interactive use of the FFmpeg command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production.`

Comment: try adding some v codec info to your CLI expression  EX  : -threads 2 -vcodec libx264

Comment: Tried this. But it didnt work. Got the same output.   ffmpeg -analyzeduration 1G -probesize 50M -i rtsp://xx:yy@192.168.1.nn:mm/tcp/av0_0 -threads 2 -vcodec libx264 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1/120 img%03d.jpg

Comment: Thanks Robert. I got the solution. I need to use rtsp_transport tcp. The following command works.  ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://bb:cc@192.168.1.xx:yy/tcp/av0_0 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 hello/img%03d.png

Comment: @kranthisai You should put this in an answer

Answer (score 3):

I need to use rtsp_transport tcp. The following command works.

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://bb:cc@192.168.1.xx:yy/tcp/av0_0 -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 hello/img%03d.png`