# Streaming an IP camera through node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg, server, ip-camera

I am trying to get an IP camera stream to run in the browser, and eventually phones. However, I am running into a problem accessing the RTSP stream through ffmpeg.
I am running the command below, substituting the correct info. I changed the camera to a static IP address and copied the IP address to STATIC_IP.

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg -i rtsp://USER:PASS@STATIC_IP:554/stream1 -fflags flush_packets -max_delay 5 -flags -global_header -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 3 -vcodec copy -y .\videos\ipcam\index.m3u8
```

The build is logging the following:

```
ffmpeg version 4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.4_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-avresample --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 70.100 / 56. 70.100
  libavcodec     58.134.100 / 58.134.100
  libavformat    58. 76.100 / 58. 76.100
  libavdevice    58. 13.100 / 58. 13.100
  libavfilter     7.110.100 /  7.110.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  9.100 /  5.  9.100
  libswresample   3.  9.100 /  3.  9.100
  libpostproc    55.  9.100 / 55.  9.100
[rtsp @ 0x11b008200] CSeq 2 expected, 1 received.
rtsp://USER:PASS@STATIC_IP:554/stream1: Server returned 400 Bad Request
```

I do not know what the CSeq 2 expected 1 received line is referring to so I am having trouble diagnosing the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This following SO post suggested making use of `rtsp_transport tcp`

> `ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://...`

[SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38886107/capture-rtsp-stream-from-ip-camera-ffmpeg)